# Ubuntu Karmic: what logs do I need to look at to figure out boot script problems

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, troubleshooting, bashrc

I made some changes to bashrc and have somehow messed up booting into gnome.  I can now only boot into gnome failsafe and have no wireless.

Where do I need to look to see what the problems are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a file in your home directory called ".xsession-errors". You can also look at /var/log/Xorg.log (or /var/log/Xorg.0.log) and at the files in /var/log/gdm. These should all contain error and warning messages from various X programs.